# How to make a UIButton change its image on click, and stay changed?

Tags: ios, uibutton, nsuserdefaults

I would like to have a button that changes it's image on click, and then stay clicked. I can use the Xcode interface builder to select different picture for 'default' and 'selected', but I want the picture I use for 'selected' to remain until the user presses the button again, and I want this all done within the button's code.

Second part to the question... what if I want this setup to last indefinitely, so that after a user restarts his phone, the button would still be selected and showing the alternate image? Could I use NSUserDefaults to save the state of the button and pass that to the image selector?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: please stop putting tags in the title. Also, please read the details of the `xcode` tag and when it should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of selected/default state of a button. You should think by yourself to an algorithm that will select/ "deselect" the button, after you find that algorithm and it's not working well edit the question and post the code and SO user will help you find the problem.